# Python way to find sum of particular item in lists

Tags: python

I have a code that will take as many lists as people want and store it into one large list. What I want to be able to do is for each sub list in the main list, find the sum of the last item, which in this case each sub list has only 4 objects [product name, units, cost, price] and then multiply it by the number of units. I was thinking along the lines of trying it like:

```
for item in mainList:
   expectedProfit = (sum(item[3])) * (item[1])
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this by chance, or am I way off in my approach?

Answer (score 2):

Use a generator expression to do the multiplication, then pass that result to `sum()`:

```
expected_profit = sum(item[-1] * item[1] for item in mainList)
```

So for each item in `mainList`, it'll multiply the last item (price) by the unit count (`item[1]`), and all those are then summed.

Demo:

```
>>> mainList = [
...      # product, count, cost, price
...      ['Frobnar', 3, 2.55, 4],
...      ['Fooznib', 20, 0.66, 2.5],
...      ['Spam (canned)', 5, 3.98, 6.99],
... ]
>>> sum(item[-1] * item[1] for item in mainList)
96.95
```